# How to replace the specific line occurence in file in bash

Tags: bash, replace, sed

Hello i need a little help with my personal project i have something like this:

sourceFile:

```
something,something,something,something,something,someth ing,
something,something,something,something,something,somethi ng,
something,something,something,something,something,someth ing,
```

I need to write my variable after the last , in specific line (i have different value for every line)

resultFile:

```
something,something,something,something,something,someth ing,result1
something,something,something,something,something,somethi ng,result2
something,something,something,something,something,someth ing,result3
```

I used this:

```
sed -i "$numberOfLine,/,/ s/,/,$actualDeparture/6" $fileName
```

but the result is:
badResultFile:

```
something,something,something,something,something,someth ing,result1
something,something,something,something,something,somethi ng,result2result1
something,something,something,something,something,someth ing,result3result2
```

I don't know why i have result2 and result1 in second line and i'm really 
desperate, because i don't know hoiw to fix this.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `actualDeparture`?

Comment: Wow you really DO have "something" like this :-). [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including the values of your variables or you're likely to get a solution that only works for one line and/or variable contents and/or when your input file is full of the text "something". And if by chance you are calling sed in a loop to do this, read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001 to learn SOME of the reasons not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your address range `$numberOfLine,/,/` all lines starting from `$numberOfLine` to next line containing `,` are processed.

And you don't need to count number of `,` in your `s` command, just replace `$`(end of line) with your variable value.

To process each line individually, try this:

```
sed -i "$numberOfLine s/$/$actualDeparture/" "$fileName"
```

Comment: Doesn't working, but it is closer then awk i used this: 
`sed -i "$lineNumber s/$/$actualDeparture/" "$fileName"` .
But in output result is on new line:
`something,something,something,something,something,something,\n
result1
something,something,something,something,something,something,\n
result2
something,something,something,something,something,something,\n
result3`

Comment: This working perfectly, thanks for help. 
`sed -i "$lineNumber s/,/,$actualDeparture/6" "$fileName"`

Answer (score 3):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $0 "result" NR }' sourceFile
```

- `print $0 "result" NR` prints each line, then string `result`, and then each line (record) number (`NR`)

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt  
something,something,something,something,something,something,
something,something,something,something,something,something,
something,something,something,something,something,something,

% awk '{ print $0 "result" NR }' file.txt
something,something,something,something,something,something,result1
something,something,something,something,something,something,result2
something,something,something,something,something,something,result3
```

Comment: The OP is not clear about that but I'm not sure he wants a concatenation of a literal `result` and `NR` as variable value. He could have used `firstresult`, `secondresult` as well.

Comment: doesn't working i used this:

`awk '{ print $0 $resultVariable $lineNumber }' $fileName`

No error, but in the file nothing happened, no change, it just print on stdout and it has one more problem, i edit my question sorry that i wasn't accurate for first time

Comment: Thanks for help but i needed `sed` solution